How to sort based on images in cell rows
I have a table that has a column that is either clicked or not.  if clicked == 1, I want to show a font-awesome checkmark in the table cell, otherwise its blank.  That all works fine. What is not working is the jquery tablesorter.  When I click the column head, nothing is sorted.  I have added the parser-input-select.min.js file with no luck.


$(function() {
  $('#serviceTable').tablesorter({
    theme: 'metro-dark',
    showProcessing: true,
    headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
    widgets: ["uitheme", "filter", "zebra", "scroller"],
    widgetOptions: {
      scroller_height: 1000,
      zebra: ["even", "odd"],
      filter_reset: ".reset",
      filter_cssFilter: "form-control input-sm",
      scroller_upAfterSort: true,
      scroller_jumpToHeader: true,
      scroller_rowHighlight: "hover",
      scroller_barWidth: null
    }
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.31.3/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.32.0/js/widgets/widget-scroller.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel='stylesheet'>

<table id='serviceTable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Allowed</th>
      <th>Difference</th>
      <th>Billable</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>





Please provide a [mcve].

yea man. Im trying.  I just got it figured out.

if you click on "Difference" header of table, you will see it sorts the numbers correctly in snippet.  if you click on "Billable",  it does not.

you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550354/jquery-tablesorter-plugin-secondary-hidden-sorting ... you have 2 ways.. 1. you may just set the data-text attribute for each of those billable <td> using a 0/1 value and they will get sortable... or 2. you may use a custom parser to bind to such column that will evaluate the cell data and will return the correspondent sortable value.

I didn't post that as answer because it's 99% a duplicate of the cited question .. just in a slightly different scenario

Nope, you guys nailed it.  Thank you a ton.

The answer I found thanks to folks in the comments was:
<tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td data-text=" //1 or 0//"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
</tr>

